# Variables not sharing between view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

In my first view controller I have a function that is caller by the press of a button.

```
    func BuyButton(sender:UIButton) {
    print("clicked cell is at row \(sender.tag)")
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CustomCell
    let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let PaymentController = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PaymentViewController") as! PaymentViewController
    print(currentCell.Test.text!) //prints fine here
    PaymentController.RecordTitle = currentCell.Test.text!
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Buy", sender: self)
}
```

In my payment view controller I define the variable as

```
    var RecordTitle = String()
```

In my view did load of my Payment View Controller I try to print the RecordTitle and nothing prints

```
    print(RecordTitle)//Nothing prints in payment view controller
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried multiple methods and none seem to work.

Comment: A more accepted "Swifty" way of **var RecordTitle = String()** is **var recordTitle = ""**. Camel-case variables and infer type when possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can change viewController by 2 method:
1: instantiateViewController
2: performSegue
but you are combining them
if you want to use first method just do like this:

```
func BuyButton(sender:UIButton) {
    print("clicked cell is at row \(sender.tag)")
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CustomCell
    let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let PaymentController = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PaymentViewController") as! PaymentViewController
    print(currentCell.Test.text!) //prints fine here
    PaymentController.RecordTitle = currentCell.Test.text!
    self.presentViewController(PaymentController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

if you are interested in second method, there is a good example in this link:
http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-swift-view-controllers/

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `prepare(segue, sender)` method and in that method get needed view controller and set **title**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Buy" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! PaymentViewController
        vc.RecordTitle = sender as? String
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to call `performSegue` with that title

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "Buy", sender: currentCell.Test.text!)
```

Comment: @HaydenBowden Have you ckecked that title is assigned in `prepare` method? And in the `viewDidLoad` you see `nil` object?